# Add timestamps to developer survey

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog, stack-overflow-developer-survey

https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016

Please add:

- When was the survey taken?
- When were the results published?

The survey results <2014 were short blog posts with timestamps on publish. The survey results for 2014-2016 were longer, more thought-out, pages (not posts) with no timestamps. I'd like to know what time of year to attribute the results to.

Comment: I see a few close votes thinking this is off topic. There are active tags for "blog" and "survey". This question couldn't be more on-topic here. Think before close voting.

Comment: This is a Stack Overflow question so I think it should be migrated to Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: The objection seems to be that this (presumably) belongs on meta.stackoverflow exclusively. I'm not sure I agree since this *doesn't* involve the operation of that site specficly. We have many programming sites and the survey *is* a project of Stack Oveflow Inc so it seems just as fitting to *this* site as any of our projects (podcasts, blogs, outreach programs, etc).

Comment: @RobertCartaino I thought I only received the survey because I am a user of [so] hence it was a survey of that site's users only.  Does it go to users of all programming sites?

Comment: @PolyGeo I just don't think it matters. SO Inc is more than just Stack Overflow Q&A and the survey is an SO Inc project that is essentially "headquartered" here.

Comment: @RobertCartaino OK - I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: @PolyGeo We usually feature something in the community bulletin to draw in programmers from all of our sites. It's branded with Stack Overflow, but it's for all developers and you don't even need an account to take it.

Comment: @RobertCartaino The new survey results are out without a timestamp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2017 edition has a [Methodology](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017#methodology) section that states:

> The survey fielded from January 12th to February 6th, consistent with last year.

The initial analysis was announced today (March 22) [on the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/22/now-live-stack-overflow-developer-survey-2017-results/). In addition, the team will be publishing more analysis and the anonymised results in the next few weeks.

For previous years, I believe there was an announcement on the blog under the [survey tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/survey/).

The survey has been pretty consistent in running for two or three weeks at the beginning of the year. I see no reason to change that pattern (and plenty of reasons to continue it). Since Stack Overflow now has an entire team dedicated to [understanding developers](https://stackoverflow.com/insights), I suspect the methodology will be even more rigorous and transparent in the coming years.

Comment: The team being [Developer Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team#DeveloperInsights) (not sure if you meant to link to them).

Comment: @NormalHuman: Correct. The survey also got some major help from our data scientists and marketing. So actually, it's hard to link to them.